# How to use CONCAT with +

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Under what circumstances is it better to use CONCAT with + over CONCAT_WS when analyzing data?

Comment: Which SQL you are using?

Comment: Thanks so much for your response Muhammad. I am taking a Google Analytics course and one of my assignments was to ask a question here.  I am using the BigQuery platform for SQL data analysis.

Comment: You can simply use the Concatenation operator `||` or  `CONCAT` function as explained in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#concat).

Comment: The function often will convert nulls to empty strings. Otherwise adding null should return null. Big Query is a platform I am less familiar with but a quick search said that I was as wrong.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, BigQuery doesn't support `CONCAT_WS`. As I know, most closest syntax is below:

```sql
SELECT ARRAY_TO_STRING(['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'], ',') AS concat_str;
```

output:

> aaa,bbb,ccc

And regarding when you have to use `CONCAT()` or `ARRAY_TO_STRING()` in BigQuery (as an alternative of `CONCAT_WS`), it highly depends on the logic your query tries to implement.

My opinion is that `ARRAY_TO_STRING()` seems to be suited for **CSV-styled string** and `CONCAT` would be preferred where strings are concatenated without a repetitive delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

SQL dialects vary quite a lot in the way they handle text-string data, both in storage and in the functions (CONCAT among others) used to manipulate that text. So a hard-core StackOverflow answer would insist you put the SQL variant in your question tags.

But your situation is not quite that.

So, let's say, for example, that you wish to use SQL  concatenation to write `www.example.com`. You could do

```
CONCAT('www', '.', 'example', '.', 'com')
```

or

```
CONCAT_WS('.', 'www', 'example', 'com')
```

As you can see, for that example CONCAT_WS is a little more concise.   And, if your app logic is built to handle that dot-separated style of names, it respects that logic.

On the other hand an expression like

```
CONCAT('surname:', user_surname)
```

is easier to express with CONCAT.

So, the answer: the choice depends on the application's data organization.

Performance-wise, the difference between CONCAT and CONCAT_WS is too small to measure, and far smaller than many other parts of satisfying a typical SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Let say you want to combine both First_name and Last_name you could say

```
CONCAT(First_name,' ',Last_name) AS full_name
```

Comment: Learn to use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to format your answer.